# Remove search box based on Magento configuration

Tags: magento, configuration, themes, customization, magento-1.9

How can we tie the displaying of the search box on all magento pages to the configuration settings for "Mage_CatalogSearch" ?

To elaborate a bit on the problem:
Magento offers to disable the output of individual modules under System -> Config -> Advanced.

Here we're able to set "Mage_CatalogSearch" to deactivated.

The search results are effectively no longer displayed, however (at least in the template we're currently using) ***the search box remains visible***.

- How can we tie the display of the search box to the setting for "Mage_CatalogSearch" ?
- Is there a better configuration setting than "Mage_CatalogSearch" to accomplish the task?
- In case the approach differs for different parts of Magento (e.g. homepage vs category page vs product detail page), I'd appreciate a guidance as to how to accomplish this for the entire system.

I'd prefer a solution that allows us to re-enable search simply by setting "Mage_CatalogSearch" to enabled again, which should trigger the search box as well as the search results to show up again, without modifying code again.

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind Regards
F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try using builtin core helper function in your .phtml

```
if(Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('MyCompany_MyModule') && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('MyCompany_MyModule'))
{ /* display searchbox */ }
```

or

```
$isActive = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules/MyCompany_MyModule/active');
if ($isActive && in_array((string)$isActive, array('true', '1')))
{ /* display searchbox */ }
```

or

```
Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('MyCompany_MyModule')->is('active', 'true'); /* which retuns true/false */
```

Comment: Brilliant ! Thank you for the quick reply! Posting the utilized code below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GunJan Metha for pointing me into the perfectly right direction!

The file to modify is (from magento base folder):
./app/design/frontend/[theme_package]/[theme]/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml

The following code was added around the original HTML piece and works like a charm:

```
   if(Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogSearch') && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_CatalogSearch')) {
?>
   <!-- here goes the original HTML that renders the search box -->
<?php
   }
?>
```